# Prerequisites for studying Introduction to probability theory by William Feller,vol 1 & vol 2?

Tags: probability, soft-question

I know calculus, real analysis, discrete mathematics and applied probability, and want to know what else do I need to know to self-study both the probability books by Feller?

Answer (score 0):

Calculus - specifically integration - is also necessary to understand Feller. Some people cover this is applied probability, but some do not.